# Characterization of quasi-isometric subsets.

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y \subset X$ is quasi-isometric to $X$. That is, suppose
\begin{equation}
X \sim_{QI} Y \subset X.
\end{equation}
I was wondering, is the inclusion $i: Y \to X$ necessarily a quasi-isometry? Equivalently, does there exists $M>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in X \hspace{3pt} \exists y_x \in Y \hspace{3pt} d(y_x,x)< M ? 
\end{equation}
Perhaps I should mention that the metric on $Y$ is the restriction of the metric on $X$, that is, $d|_{Y\times Y}$. I believe I'm having difficulties answering this because I don't know many examples. I would also be very grateful if someone could share what kind of examples do they think about when solving this kind of problems.
By the way, I just started studying geometric group theory (I'm currently reading section 5.4 on Clara Loh's book), so an elementary argument would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider the rank 2 free group $F\langle a,b \rangle$ with Cayley graph $\Gamma\langle a,b \rangle$. Inside $F\langle a,b \rangle$ we have a rank 2 free group $F \langle a^2,b^2 \rangle$ of infinite index. One could take our counterexample to be simply inclusion $F \langle a^2,b^2 \rangle \hookrightarrow F\langle a,b \rangle$, using word metrics on each.

But to make this more geometric, let's consider the corresponding inclusion of Cayley graphs $i : \Gamma\langle a^2,b^2 \rangle \hookrightarrow \Gamma\langle a,b\rangle$. Clearly $i$ is *not* a quasi-isometry, because for example points on the ray $ababababababab....$ in $\Gamma\langle a,b\rangle$ get farther and farther from $\Gamma\langle a^2,b^2 \rangle$.

But there does exist a quasi-isometry $h : \Gamma\langle a,b \rangle \to \Gamma\langle a^2,b^2 \rangle$, in fact we can take $h$ to be a homeomorphism that multiplies the metric by a factor of $2$, taking each $a$ edge of the domain to an $a^2$ edge of the range, and similarly for $b$.

Comment: Very nice! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Do you think it is an interesting question to find sufficient conditions for this to hold? For example, I'm pretty sure that all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ that are quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy this.

Comment: I suspect there are certain interesting questions along these lines. The example of $\mathbb Z$ is a reasonable one to ask but pretty simple to resolve.

Comment: @DiegoLeipen If I remember it correctly, this is called "coarse cohophian property" if every quasiisometric embedding of a space into itself is a quasiisometry. Universal covers of closed connected aspherical manifolds have it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'll look it up, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: There is also an implication for word hyperbolic groups $G$ (or equivalently its Cayley graph), expressed in terms of the Gromov boundary $\partial G$: if every topological embedding $\partial G \to \partial G$ is a homeomorphism then every QI-embedding $G \to G$ is a quasi-isometry.

Answer (score 3):

A simple counterexample:

$X$: the upper half-plane $\{re^{i\theta}:r\ge 0,0\le\theta\le\pi\}$, with the Euclidean distance

$Y$: the upper right corner $\{re^{i\theta}:r\ge 0,0\le\theta\le\pi/2\}$.

Clearly the isometric inclusion $Y\subset X$ is not a QI. But $Y$ is QI to $X$ via the mapping $f:re^{i\theta}\mapsto re^{2i\theta}$ (that is, $f(z)=z^2/|z|$): indeed $f$ is a $(1,2)$-bilipschitz homeomorphism.

Comment: Very nice and simple! Thanks for sharing :)